# How can I manipulate a string given as a parameter in a C program?

Tags: c

For example I want to create a program called "search.c" that searches for a certain caracter in a string given as a parameter like this :

```
./search.c "myString"
```

How can I store "myString" in a variable so I can manipulate it

Comment: Keyword: *command-line argument*

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   ...
}
```

`"myString"` will be accessible in your program via `argv[1]`.